# Elasticsearch - how to search long articles

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an articles website that has legal articles. I am trying to use elastic search through searchkick gem. When I index, I get this error.

```
Document contains at least one immense term in field="detail" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766)
```

Now all the help articles I read here are about skipping/ignoring the field or not analyzing it. I don't want this field to be ignored. This field has the article. How do I search this article?

Do I divide the article into field1 field2 field3 and so on keeping less than 32766 bytes in each... There must be a better way to do it I must be missing something

Comment: The problem seems to not be the length of the article itself, but the length of one of its terms. Which analyzer are you using ?

Comment: I use searchkick ... it looks like it uses searchkick_search_shingle

Comment: Also, it is the length of article because I pasted "abc xyz" multiple times and when it exceeds certain length, it gives out the same error